# Sending a variable to a widget

Tags: android

I'm trying to send a variable from my main activity to a widget. I can do this by changing:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
```

to

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds, String mValue)
```

And adding the variable when I call onUpdate in my main activity. However this seems to break the functionality of items in the widget. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    myUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds, "");
}

public void myUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds, String mValue) {
    ...
}
```

And call `myUpdate' instead of 'onUpdate' in you Activity.